# Intersection theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry

Consider points $0, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $B_r(0)$ - closed ball centered in zero ($b \not\in B_r(0)$).
Let's take $c \in B_r(0)$ and make $[c, b]$. Consider body $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ constructed by all these segments. Let's take point $kb$, $k < 1$. The question is: isn't it obvious that $\operatorname{dist}(kb, \partial V) = (1-k)r$?

In $\mathbb{R}^k$, $k \le 3$ it's obvious. How to get general proof.

Comment: If $[c,b]$ denotes a Euclidean line segment, the solid has an obvious rotational symmetry about the line containing $[0,b]$, so looking at the case $n = 2$ suffices. (Incidentally, there's a silent assumption that $b$ is outside the ball.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang edited. Yes a think so too. Maybe the most strict way to prove it is to consider $f : R^n \to R^n$ s.a. $f(x) = kb + (1 - k)x$?